# how to retrieve data by connecting MongoDB with username and Password using native node.js driver

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I already have username and password for my mongodb.

I want to retrieve data from a collection in mongodb by using node.js native driver.

then how to connect to mongodb using node.js

Thanks

Comment: are you using mongoose or without mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

**[Using mongoClient](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/client/) :**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
  db.close();
});
```

**[Using Mongoose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose):**

```
//Import the mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Set up default mongoose connection
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
//Get the default connection
var db = mongoose.connection;
//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

Comment: Thx for reply - @Vishnu Mishra . I got the solution